# Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\setswim.php on line 13

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried to update datas from form in edit1.php to setswim.php
but it gives an error:

> Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\setswim.php on line 9

```
<?php

include "includes/db.php";
$checklogin = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `students`");

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE students SET student_number='" . $_POST['student_number'] . "',student_name='" . $_POST['student_name'] . "',student_last='" . $_POST['student_last'] . "',id_student='" . $_POST['id_student'] . "',student_address='" . $_POST['student_address'] . "',student_collage='" . $_POST['student_collage'] . "',student_datebirth='" . $_POST['student_datebirth'] . "',student_email='" . $_POST['student_email'] . "'");
    //   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $result = $con->query($sql);

    if (!$result) {
        mysqli_error($con) . "[ $sql]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Well I guess you're doing something wrong when calling to `$con->query` cause sometimes you send a mysqli result object, and sometimes you send a string. Need to see your db.php code in order to see whats going on behind the scenes.

Comment: In setswim.php, you're passing an attempted mysqli_result into mysqli_query at `$result = $con->query($sql);`. That won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE students ...");
$result = $con->query($sql);
```

A mysql result is stored in `$sql` and then used as in `query()`, which takes a string.

Only needs to be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE students ...");
```

or

```
$result = $con->query("UPDATE students ...");
```

but not both. I would use `$con->query();`

Comment: You likely have a problem with your update statement and will need to investigate the contents of the `$result` variable to see if anything went wrong. [this is the structure of `$result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: $result = $con->query("UPDATE students SET student_number='".$_POST['student_number']."',student_name='".$_POST['student_name']."',student_last='".$_POST['student_last']."',id_student='".$_POST['id_student']."',student_address='".$_POST['student_address']."',student_collage='".$_POST['student_collage']."',student_datebirth='".$_POST['student_datebirth']."',student_email='".$_POST['student_email']."'");
t

Comment: I do not know. You need to check for errors after `query()`.